# Create numpy dtype from IEEE-754 types

Tags: python, numpy, binary

[IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) defines the floating point types `binary16`, `binary32` and `binary64`.  Creating a `numpy.dtype` for these types however does not accept these string names for types.  Is there a way to create them from the names directly instead of using the following mapping?

```
import numpy as np

IEEE_TO_NUMPY_DTYPE = {'binary16': np.dtype('f2'),   # 16 bit float
                       'binary32': np.dtype('f4'),   # 32 bit float 
                       'binary64': np.dtype('f8')}   # 64 bit float
```

Comment: I could well be missing the point, but these are the same types as `float16`, `float32` and `float64`, aren't they? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: @NPE - Yes they are the same, but since the names `binary16` etc are standard (IEEE 754) I was just wondering if `numpy` provided a more straightforward way to create a `dtype` than having to map them.  Just curious.

Comment: What's wrong with `binary16 = np.dtype('f2')` etc.?